Are the weights of my logomark and logotype appropriate?
Regarding this logo design, I am unsure whether the weight/proportion of the logo and the logotype is appropriate or not.
And, is the kerning appropriate for the logotype?

Edit: Adjusted the crystal and change the wordmark about the same width of the logomark. Is this version has better balance and visual harmony? I am fine with the dominance of the logomark.


Font choice, placement, and kerning are all subjective choices, and as such there is no correct answer, and so I'm not going to add an answer here as it would just be mere opinion. However if you want my personal opinion, there's too much space between the ROUS letters, and since the logo is very bold I think you could use a heavier weight font, also I don't particularly like the font, it's too wide.

.. just not a fan of logos where there's a random shape above a simple straight typeset word. It doesn't convey anything about the company and rarely, if ever, leas any lasting impression.

The question has been expanded. This is an answer to the new problems.
In this version https://i.sstatic.net/H3LIufRO.png the black geometric shapes are so massive that the text becomes a bystander. Someone suggested making them larger than they were originally, because then the relation was the opposite. But now they are much bigger than what's suggested. The logo should be the graphic items and text together. You have now big black blocks and some unrelated small text below it.
If you want to increase the mass of the blocks use them to draw something which holds the text:

Or make the text and the big blocks to belong to a common holder:

(sorry for unsharp text and poorly drawn graphic elements)

Yes, grouping the logomark and wordmark looks better if both are the same width. I know that the proportions are subjective, I have found the right size to suit my needs. Thanks.

As it's said in old comments, let the letters have equal spaces. The original crystal set doesn't augment the wide and thick text. It's like a separate item. But it's no more puny if you make it a part of a frame:

Tune the sizes and the distances of the parts in a final usage example:


Make the logo taller and place the letters manually for equal spacing. Both of these are already said, but here it's done without anything oblique. The text may be badly typeset for reading long paragraps, but here it's a single image.

The apparent weights can be adjusted also with colors and effects. And the final application where the logo is used must be taken into the account. The usage in a product must be designed by a professional separately, because the appearance of the product is a whole. Here the text is heavier:


Thanks for the comment. I learned how to adjust the letter space from your example.
